# RS&GIS plugin produces no outputs

Tags: qgis-plugins, landsat, landsat-8

I'm trying to look at some landsat images and thought I would give the RS&GIS a go, as a way of creating true and false colour composites. I'd like to visually inspect the vegetation my project area.

Unfortunately, when I try to run the plugin it produces no outputs. The dialogue box notes the following `"IndexError: list index out of range"`.

I've already tried the below but without success:

- removing all spaces from the file path
- using different raw inputs (compressed and uncompressed)
- with and without the clipping function